# How to start a long-running process from a Django view?

Tags: python, django, long-running-processes

I need to run a process that might take hours to complete from a Django view. I don't need to know the state or communicate with it but I need that view to redirect away right after starting the process.

I've tried using `subprocess.Popen`, using it within a new `threading.Thread`, `multiprocessing.Process`.  However, the parent process keeps hanging until child terminates. The only way that *almost* gets it done is using a fork. Obviously that isn't good as it leaves a zombie process behind until parent terminates.

That's what I'm trying to do when using fork:

```
if os.fork() == 0:
    subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python", script_path, "-v"])
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_to_redirect'))
```

So, is there a way to run a completely independent process from a Django view with minimal casualties? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+long-running.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107826/python-long-running-daemon-job-processor, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805120/python-task-server

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if this will be suitable for your case, nevertheless here is what I do: I use a task queue (via a django model); when the view is called, it enters a new record in the tasks and redirects happily. Tasks in turn are executed by cron on a regular basis independently from django.

Edit: cron calls the relevant (and custom) django command to execute the task.

Answer (score 5):

First of all - try to using cron for you task, as early say shanyu.

If it doesn't suit you - then try to use [CeleryProject](http://www.celeryproject.org/), for task Queue for Django. For working it uses [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). And here is a little [overview](http://www.celeryproject.org/introduction.html#overview) for simple using of basing futures

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/JobsScheduling

Is a nice library that that you can use to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the code in kronos.py to see one solution to this problem.

http://www.razorvine.net/download/kronos.py